# EmberJS: in RC2, how to use "needs" for a controller when {{render}} is called multiple times?

Tags: ember.js

Say you have something like this:

```
Parent hasMany Children
Child hasMany GrandChildren
```

and every nested Child and GrandChild is rendered with its own controller (using the ability to use {{render}} multiple times in RC2).

Is it possible to have each GrandChild controller access data from its "parent" Child controller using the "needs" API?

Please see this jsfiddle for a failing example: http://jsfiddle.net/p73jq/32/

UPDATE: simpler jsfiddle (only two levels): http://jsfiddle.net/8V9xQ/1/

Thanks a lot,

PJ

Comment: You can't really use the needs API for this as far as I know since it only works for singleton controllers. Cf here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/documentation-needs-api-is-it-only-for-singleton-controllers/911/4. So I ended up binding properties myself. Typically: from "Child", create a reference to itself in its GrandChildren. Then create the binding.