# EmberJS: how to use the "needs" API for controllers?

Tags: ember.js

Two weeks ago I posted an issue that I thought was related to the updated {{render}} in RC2: 
[EmberJS: in RC2, how to use "needs" for a controller when {{render}} is called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725454/emberjs-in-rc2-how-to-use-needs-for-a-controller-when-render-is-called-m)

Now, I think it is either broader than this, or I am misunderstanding how to use the "needs" API since it also happens when using the older 'itemController'.

Consider the following:

```
App.Parent = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    children: null, // An Ember array of Child objects
});

App.Child = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
});

App.ParentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: 'parent',
});
```

My templates are like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{#each parent in App.parents itemController='Parent'}}
        {{partial 'parent'}}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_parent">
    In parent: {{controller}}<br>
    Name: {{name}}<br>
    <br>
    {{#each child in children itemController='Child'}}
        {{ partial 'child' }}
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_child">
    Child name: {{name}}<br>
    Parent Name: {{controllers.parent.name}}<br>
    <br>
</script>
```

Why is {{controllers.parent.name}} always null?

http://jsfiddle.net/8V9xQ/5/

Thanks

PJ

Comment: Because the `controller` does not have a property name, it's `content` does however. Try `{{controllers.parent.content.name}}`

Comment: It's not because of that. If you do `{{controllers.parent}}` in the child partial, you'll get a completely different instance - the one which Ember created as a singleton. My guess is the `needs` API right now is only for singleton controllers.

Comment: Thomas, also, my understanding is the controller is just proxy-ing to the underlying model by default. So you should never really have to do controllerX.content.property. You should be able to omit the ".content".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the `needs` API for this, simply write `{{parent.name}}` instead of `{{controllers.parent.name}}` in your child template and delete the `needs: 'parent'` line from `App.ChildController`.

You refer to singleton controllers with the `needs` API, while an `itemController` is not a singleton.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I realize I over simplified my example a bit. I need to use infos from my parent in my child controller. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8V9xQ/7/   Do you know a way to make it work then?

Comment: Also, on this: "You refer to singleton controllers with the needs API" that is (unfortunately) my conclusion as well. But I could not find any reference to this in the guides. Do you know where it is documented?

Comment: I think you should declare these sort of relationships on the models, rather than the controllers. Controllers are not designed to model relationships, but to feed the view with the associated model, and to declare some additional properties, methods, etc.

Comment: The non-singleton controller behavior is not really documented (maybe in the source), as the API is considered to be unstable regarding to this, as of RC2.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. On this: "I think you should declare these sort of relationships on the models, rather than the controllers." It seems to me there are use cases where you might not want this. For example: say I want the eldest child in the family to have specific properties in the UI. There is no reason to persist this info so it should be in a controller. Yet, the only way is to know about the parent controller from the child one. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I think I do. And I do agree with you in theory. But as the current state of non-singleton controllers is what it is, I'd make an exception here and implement this stuff on the model layer. I mean not the view-related properties, but the relations how they connect to each other. Then maybe wait some and see if the API evolves to fit my needs, then refactor. Sometimes it's not that easy to use the best practices with an unreleased software :)